# Three argument operator: Local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I have the following piece of code...

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ThreeArgumentOperator {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test;
        System.out.println(test = getValue() == null ? "" : test);
    }

    public static String getValue() {
        if (RANDOM.nextBoolean()) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The Eclipse compiler (I am using Juno) reports the following error:

> The local variable test may not have been initialized

My question is: Should not the compiler report in this case that it rather cannot convert `boolean` to `String`? I understand that the operator `==` takes precedence over `=` and therefore the compiler should complain about the casting, instead it complains about possibly not initialized value.

When I change the following line

`System.out.println(test = getValue() == null ? "" : test);`

to

`System.out.println((test = getValue()) == null ? "" : test);`

everything works fine.

EDIT: I have also tried to compile it using `javac` directly. It gives the same error.

```
error: variable test might not have been initialized
System.out.println(test = getValue() == null ? "" : test);
```

Comment: It should, and in my case it does.

Comment: @NPE Does it mean that you get `Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String`? If so, what compiler do you use?

Comment: I've tested this in my Eclipse right now and the compiler gives me the error you're describing. I'm using Sun's JDK 7 by the way.

Comment: *don't do that, please*, it's bug prone.

Comment: @RC It does not matter whether it bug prone or not. It is about the fact that the compiler gives a misleading message in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error the compiler is providing you is correct. According to the operator precedence, `==` will be evaluated first, then your ternary operator `? :`. That means, the flow of logic is as follows:

```
getValue() == null
```

In order to continue, let's assume the result of this was `false`. The next expression that follows:

```
false ? "" : test
```

The result of this then is `test`. And our final expression...

```
test = test
```

But `test` was never initialized, hence the error.

Comment: This is a perfect explanation! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it was useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand where the problem is. The first expression is

```
test = getValue() == null ? "" : test
```

Which means: `test` is initialized with

- the empty string if `getValue()` returns null
- the value of `test` otherwise

Since test has not been initialized yet, you can't initialize `test` with itself, hence the error message.

The second expression is

```
(test = getValue()) == null ? "" : test
```

which means:

- initialize `test` with the result of `getValue()`
- compare `test` with `null`
- if `test` is null the expression evaluates to the empty string
- otherwise it evaluates to the value of `test`

Why shouldn't it compile?

Comment: Where did I write that the second one should not compile? Anyway, thanks for your answer as well.

Comment: Ok, I read my question once again and reordered some sentences, it really might have been a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It makes perfect sense to me.

The second compiling version is actually two separate statements. It is equivalent to this code:

```
test = getValue();
System.out.println(test == null ? "" : test);
```

The first assigns a value to `test`:

```
test = getValue();
```

Now `test` has a value. The second statement is able to determine the expession result value in case `test` is not null.

The first non-compiling version is one statement, and because `test` has no value yet, the value to assign `test` (ie `test`) is unknown.